# How to make mobs change textures based on their custom name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been trying for the past day to figure out how to make it so that when a vindicator is named "Enchanter", it switches its textures.

None of the tutorials I have watched work. I've done everything I can think of and I am out of options now, I even searched to see if this question has been asked before, and I either cant find it, or it simply does not work.

This is in java 1.16.5 with a custom resource pack.

Comment: Does it *have* to be the custom name that triggers the texture? If so, why? What about setting a different type of flag?

Comment: Yes it does, because if its something else then I don't understand it. I don't even know how to measure anything else, names is the only thing I now that has worked in the past other then biome specific and that wont work since I need it to be in several biomes at once.

Comment: does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with vanilla, though OptiFine has it as a feature. [Here's a documentation of it.](https://github.com/sp614x/optifine/blob/master/OptiFineDoc/doc/random_entities.properties)


The custom texture for the mob must be named `vindicator<num>.png` inside the `assets\minecraft\optifine\random\entity\illager` folder, where `<num>` is a number (starts at 1.)

Inside the same folder, you'll also need a `.properties` file with the same name as the vanilla texture (meaning it would be `vindicator.properties`.) Here's how its contents would look like:

```
name.<num>=Enchanter
```

- `<num>` being the same number as the custom texture has in its name.

This should now display the custom texture to the vindicator with the name "Enchanter"

Comment: somehow this is not working, I dont know why but when I do this it simply does the default textures even though everything is in place.

Comment: Does this work for 1.16.5 for you, or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Does this answer work for other people?

Comment: @anomanous It'll only show the custom texture for the players that have OptiFine installed. Also, I forgot that it should be `...\minecraft\optifine\random\entity` instead of just `...\minecraft\optifine\entity`, sorry about that!

Comment: its still not working, I have optifine installed, custom models used, but its STILL not working, the number used is 2, ut when I try to do it it simply uses the normal texture!

Comment: Ok, I got it to work using a bit of a resource pack called "creature variety", so im just gonna accept this. Thanks for the help but it was missing some weird green *'s.